# Is the variation of a metric with respect to a metric with a different signature, zero?

Tags: differential-geometry, metric-tensor, differentiation, variational-calculus

I have a problem that involves calculating the variation of a metric $ \bar{g}_{\alpha\beta} $ with +3 signature with respect to a metric $ g_{\alpha\beta} $ with a signature of +1. Both metrics have the same spatial dimension of 3. The metrics are related by $g_{\alpha\beta}=\bar{g}_{\alpha\beta}-2u_{\alpha}u_{\beta} $ where u is a unit vector in $ \bar{g} $, i.e. $u_{\alpha}u^{\alpha}=1  $, and $ u_{\alpha}u^{\alpha}=-1 $ in g. Since the signature of a metric is constant everywhere, it seems trivial that $$\dfrac{\delta \bar{g}_{\alpha\beta}}{\delta g_{\alpha\beta}}   =0.$$ Am I missing something?

Comment: Why are you only differentiating wrt. the same indices $\alpha\beta$? Why are you not considering more generally $\dfrac{\delta \bar{g}_{\alpha\beta}}{\delta g_{\gamma\delta}}$?

Comment: Why does that seem trivial to you?

Comment: Qmechanic. In particular, I am calculating the same components of one metric with respect to the other. The more general situation of doing the calculation involving different indices could also be entertained.

Comment: gi255 as stated, if the signature is constant everywhere, that means one cannot vary it to accommodate the other metric with a different signature. That suggests to me that the variation must vanish; but as stated, am I missing something?

Comment: How is the barred metric defined in terms of the unbarred metric?

Comment: Qmechanic $g_{\alpha\beta}=\bar{g}_{\alpha\beta}-2u_{\alpha}u_{\beta} $ where u is a unit vector in $ \bar{g} $ and $ u_{\alpha}u^{\alpha}=-1 $ in g.

Comment: I think your argument isnot valid. It sounds good but is not. Take e.g x^2 which is positive and vary it on the domain [-1,1] over x^2-2 which is negative on the domain (or -x^2 or whatever you like). Result is 1 (-1 in the second exampke) and not zero.

Comment: Lalala it seems you have not considered that there are 2 different metrics involved with an application of unit vectors. Your example is therefore meaningless.

Answer (score -1):

The question is more complex than I thought. However, it seems that $\dfrac{\delta \bar{g}_{\alpha\beta}}{\delta g_{\alpha\beta}}   =0$ is the only condition that satisfies the two metrics defined by $g_{\alpha\beta}=\bar{g}_{\alpha\beta}-2u_{\alpha}u_{\beta} $ where u is a unit vector in $ \bar{g} $, i.e. $u_{\alpha}u^{\alpha}=1  $, and $ u_{\alpha}u^{\alpha}=-1 $ in g. We can check that $ g^{\alpha\beta}=\bar{g}^{\alpha\beta}-2u^{\alpha}u^{\beta} $ is the inverse of $ g_{\alpha\beta} $ by calculating $ g^{\alpha\beta} g_{\alpha\beta} $ to be the dimension of the space (n or 3 in this case). Let's assume $\dfrac{\delta \bar{g}_{\alpha\beta}}{\delta g_{\alpha\beta}} \neq 0$. With $ \delta $ standing for $\dfrac{\delta} {\delta g_{\alpha\beta}} $, we have $ g^{\alpha\beta}\delta(u_{\alpha}u_{\beta})=-u_{\alpha}u_{\beta} \delta g^{\alpha\beta}$ from $ u_{\alpha}u^{\alpha}=-1 $ and $ \delta g_{\alpha\beta}=\delta \bar{g}_{\alpha\beta}-2\delta (u_{\alpha}u_{\beta}) $. Calculating $ g^{\alpha\beta}\delta g_{\alpha\beta} $ gives $\bar{g}^{\alpha\beta}\delta g_{\alpha\beta}=g^{\alpha\beta}\delta \bar{g}_{\alpha\beta} $. Since $ \delta g=1 $, we have $ \bar{g}=(\bar{g} -2u\otimes u)\dfrac{\delta \bar{g}}{\delta g} $. This requires $ \dfrac{\delta \bar{g}}{\delta g}=1 $ and $u\otimes u=0  $ which is impossible. This contradicts the assumption that $\dfrac{\delta \bar{g}_{\alpha\beta}}{\delta g_{\alpha\beta}}   \neq0$. The only solution is then $\dfrac{\delta \bar{g}_{\alpha\beta}}{\delta g_{\alpha\beta}}   =0$ and $\dfrac{\delta u_{\alpha}u_{\beta}}{\delta g_{\alpha\beta}}   =-1/2$.